# How to skip a field in column using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal, scripting

I have this data here:

```
Name,Team,First Test, Second Test, Third Test
Tom,Red,5,17,22
Joe,Green,3,14,22
Maria,Blue,6,18,21
Fred,Blue,2,15,23
Carlos,Red,-1,15,24
Phuong,Green,7,19,21
Enrique,Green,3,16,20
Nancy,Red,9,12,24
```

I would like to skip field 3 ($3) in row 6 when I'm finding the average of the First Test since it's a negative.

How would I skip over that particular value and have all the fields still add up in the First column?

I know that the next command skips over the whole row, is there a command that will skip a particular field?

Thank you.

EDIT

Sorry. Here is how the output should look like, I already have the Averages of test two and three, just need help with the average for test one.

```
Average for Test 1: 5
Average for Test 2: 15.75
Average for Test 3: 22.125
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Please always add expected output to your post with code tags.

Comment: I apologize for that, thank you for telling me.

Comment: @jshakil: For 3rd column alone, `awk -v FS="," '($3+0)>0{sum+=$3; count++}END{print (count!=0)?(sum/count):0}' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1 {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) if($i>=0) {s[i]+=$i; c[i]++}} 
           END  {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print "Average for Test " (i-2) ": " s[i]/c[i]}' file

Average for Test 1: 5
Average for Test 2: 15.75
Average for Test 3: 22.125
```

assumes there isat least one record with non-negative value, if not guard the prints with `c[i]>0`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As OP told he needs to negate negative values in fields so providing that solution now.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{print;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i<0?"":$i,i==NF?RS:",")}}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Name,Team,First Test, Second Test, Third Test
Tom,Red,5,17,22
Joe,Green,3,14,22
Maria,Blue,6,18,21
Fred,Blue,2,15,23
Carlos,Red,,15,24
Phuong,Green,7,19,21
Enrique,Green,3,16,20
Nancy,Red,9,12,24
```